# VBA macro to find partial match in 2 columns on 2 sheets and copy value from sheet 2 to sheet 1

Tags: excel, vba

I am a VBA beginner but I’ve already learned a lot by searching this forum and I am (sometimes) able to modify code to my own needs. However I am completely stuck with a problem. I’ve already spent hours trying to modify examples I found online, but I simply don’t understand VBA well enough to make it work. I would really appreciate it if someone would be so kind to help me out with the following problem.

I have a workbook with 2 sheets.
Column B on sheet 1 contains hundreds of rows with urls (they look like this: https://website/news/2021/title-of-news-article). The column has a header.
Column D on sheet 2 contains rows with only the last part of some of these urls (title-of-news-article). This column also has a header.
Column E on sheet 2 contains values corresponding with the partial urls in column D on sheet 2. Also with a header.

I need Excel to compare column D on sheet 2 with column B on sheet 1. If there is a partial match I would like Excel to copy the corresponding value from column E on sheet 2 to the corresponding row in column F on sheet 1.

I already found VBA-code that enabled me to achieve this for exact matches. I am using a macro like the one below. But I can’t figure out how to do achieve this for partial matches. Perhaps I need a different solution? If you need more information, I'd be glad to provide it. Thanks in advance!

```
    Sub Test
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, FR As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set w1 = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set w2 = Worksheets("sheet1")
    For Each c In w1.Range("F2", w1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
      FR = 0
      On Error Resume Next
      FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns(1), 0)
      On Error GoTo 0
      If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("E" & FR).value = c.Offset(, 1)
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub`
```

Comment: You could try using the `Find` method instead, which allows for partial matches.

Comment: Btw none of the ranges in your code appear to tally with your description?

Comment: `Match` allows Wildcard if you are matching String and match type is 0 so try `FR = Application.Match("*" & c & "*", w2.Columns(1), 0)`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Like I wrote in my post: I am a total beginner... I get by by modifying other people's code. If you could perhaps point me to an example that is easy to understand I might be able to modify it to fit my need.

Comment: @SJR The code was used for another part of the worksheet. So the ranges don't correspond with the question that I asked. I am now trying to modify the macro to use wildcards, like Raymond suggested. But I am having difficulty understanding the code. Not sure what to modify in the ranges to make it work.

Comment: So you want to loop through every cell in D (sheet2), see if the cell appears in B (sheet1) and if it does copy the value from E (sheet2) to F (sheet1). Is that right? Not sure Match will cope with that because if I understand correctly you want to match the whole of the entry in D with part of a cell in B? The wildcard would work if you wanted to match part of the entry in D.

Comment: @SJR. Rows in column D on sheet 2 will sometimes contain the last part of complete urls in column B on sheet 1. I want to loop through all those rows on sheet 2 to check if that is the case. If so, I want to have the corresponding values from column E (sheet 2) to be copied to column F (on sheet 1). Your suggestion is to work the other way around? Not sure if I understand your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I may not have got all the details correct, but see how you get on.

```
Sub Test()

Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim c As Range, r As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set w1 = Worksheets("sheet1") 'think these names make more sense!
Set w2 = Worksheets("sheet2")

For Each c In w2.Range("D2", w2.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'loop through D
    Set r = w1.Columns(2).Find(What:=c.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then  'found in B
        w1.Range("F" & r.Row).Value = c.Offset(, 1).Value 'copy E to F
    End If
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @JSR Thank you! It does something but it doesn't work correctly yet. But I think I can modify this to get it to work. I will have to try later and will let you know if this works.

Comment: Hi @JSR, your code works like a charm! Thank you for helping me out with this. It nearly drove me crazy so you saved me a one way trip to an asylum. ;-)

Comment: More than I could have hoped for! Glad it worked.